# Loop of intensive processing and serializing - how to completely clean memory after each serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, memory-management, out-of-memory

In my C# console application, I instantiate an object MyObject of type MyType. This object contains 6 very large arrays, some of them containing elements of primitive type, others elements of other reference types. The latter can in turn contain big arrays. In order to instantiate all these arrays, I do some intensive processing, which lasts for about 2 minutes.

The machine I'm working on has 4 GB RAM, on a 32bit Windows. Before running my console app, the available memory is at about 2413 MB, and right before finishing, the available memory goes to about 300-400 MB.

After I assign values for all my arrays in the object MyObject, I'm serializing it. My objective is to instantiate and serialize 50 objects like this one. So after serializing, I set to null all the arrays. [This does not reflect immediately in Task Manager, where the available memory is still 300-400 Mo. So I assume the GC does not collect immediately.] Right after this, I'm reexecuting the method that instantiates the arrays in MyObject. I get a system out of memory exception almost immediately. I'm thinking this is not the right approach to effectively manage memory in .NET.

So my question is this: knowing that processing one object of type MyType, like MyObject, "fits" in the available memory resources, how can I instantiate one object of type MyType, serialize it, then completely clean ALL the memory that was used for this purpose? And then, either reinstantiate the same object, or a new object of the same type? So that I the end I get with 50 different serialized objects of type MyType?

Thanks.

Updating question with code. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class MyType
{
    int[] intArray; int[] intArray2;
    double[] doubleArray; 
    RefType1[] refType1Array; 
    RefType2[] refType2Array;
    RefType3[] refType3Array;

    public MyType (params)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)    
        {    
            instantiateArrays();
            serializeObject();
            releaseMemory(); 
        }
    }                            

    private void instantiateArrays()
    {
        //instantiate all the primitive arrays with 50.000 elements per array
        //instantiate refType1Array with 300 elements, refType2Array with 3000 elements and 
            //refType3Array with 150 elements
        //lasts about 2 minutes
    }

    private void serializeObject()
    {
        Stream fileStream = File.Create(filePath);
        BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
        serializer.Serialize(fileStream, this);
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    private void releaseMemory()
    {
        intArray = null;
        intArray2 = null;
        doubleArray = null;
        refType1Array = null;
        refType2Array = null;
        refType3Array = null;
    }
}
```

RefType1 contains integer and double fields, and another array of integers with, on average, 50 elements. RefType2 and RefType3 contain integer and double fields, and another array of reference type RefType4. On average, this array contains 500 objects. Each RefType4 object contains an array of 15 integers, on average.

Comment: Technically, you can use GC.Collect(2) to initiate total garbage cleaning; but it's also possible that you could have, say, memory leak, so please provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can clean memory by this command:

```
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: This seems to have did the trick, at least it doesn't crash on the second run. I'll update this post to let you know if it still works after 50 runs (or more). Thanks